# Can't get nested StartOperation to show up in the filter dropdown

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, logging, azure-application-insights

I have an ASP.NET Core application configured to log to Application Insights. I also have this method that I use to create dependencies within the Application Insights timeline:

```cs
private void TestLogOperations()
{
    using (IOperationHolder<DependencyTelemetry> topHolder = telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("TopOperation"))
    {
        logger.LogWarning("top holder log");

        using (IOperationHolder<DependencyTelemetry> innerHolder = telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("InnerOperation"))
        {
            logger.LogWarning("inner holder log");
        }
    }
}
```

The operations correclty appear nested within the timeline:

[image: The timeline of dependencies]

But when I want to filter by dependency (e.g I only want to filter logs within "InnerOperation"), they don't show up in the dropdown, only the top request operation is shown (localhost:5000 | POST User/Post):

[image: Filters now working]

I know it's possible to filter by dependencies because I've worked with projects that did it, but how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my test, this is the default behavior for **DependencyTelemetry**.

If you want to show what you want in your post, you should change **DependencyTelemetry** to **RequestTelemetry**.

Here is the test code:

```
        private void TestLogOperations()
        {
            using (IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry> topHolder = telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("TopOperation1"))
            {
                //telemetryClient.TrackTrace("top holder log 111");
                _logger.LogWarning("top holder log 1");

                using (IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry> innerHolder = telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("InnerOperation1"))
                {
                    //telemetryClient.TrackTrace("inner holder log 1 111");
                    _logger.LogWarning("inner holder log 1");
                }
            }
        }
```

And the test result:

[image]